# Correct type for onChange in testing input props with Enzyme in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test props of react form. I'm working in React with Typescript. I have particular password input like below:

```
<input
                type="password"
                className="my-2"
                onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                value={password}
            />
```

with function onChange:

```
 const handlePasswordChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const passwordValue = event.target.value.trim();
        setPassword(passwordValue);
    };
```

I'm trying to test props like below:

```
import React, {ChangeEventHandler} from 'react'
import {shallow, ShallowWrapper} from "enzyme";
import Login from './';

describe('<Logn /> with props test', () => {
    const loginConfig = {
        email: "kmichalski314@gmail.com",
        password: "testvalue",
        dispatch: (param: string) => {
            console.log("test")
        }
    }
    let container: ShallowWrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
        container = shallow(<Login {...loginConfig}/>);
    })
    it('should have proper props for password field', () =>{
        console.log(container.find('input[type="password"]').props());
        expect(container.find('input[type="password"]').props()).toEqual({
            type: "password",
            className: "my-2",
            value: "testvalue",
            onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
        });
    })
})
```

My question is how can I corretly typeonChange function in toEqual assertion?
Jest doesn't recognize **onChange: ChangeEventHandler**

I have an syntax error now:
[image]

Comment: You cant use a type in a place where value is expected

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I can only assert: onChange: expect.any(Function). It works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should use a comma instead of a semicolon